# I can't generate localization files

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, dart-pub, flutter-localizations

ERROR: Failed to generate localization files.
RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 9..11: 6
Process finished with exit code 2
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter
local_auth: ^2.1.3
loggy: ^2.0.3
intl: ^0.18.0

Answer (score 0):

i find out the answer. I should create some yaml file where i post my path, template-arb-file, and output-localization-file